# getting error on mysql query that I use UNION

Tags: mysql

My SQL query

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*,categories_2625729.title AS category_title,categories_2625729.id AS category,c.id as cid, c.title, '' as `introtext`, 'com_hpj_content.ad' as content_type, '' as banner, '' as `fulltext`, '' as sheettext, c.publish_up, c.publish_down, c.price, c.advertiser_id, c.seller_id, c.sold, c.soldupdated,0 AS is_favorite
FROM `jos_hpj_content_item` AS a
LEFT JOIN jos_categories AS categories_2625729 ON categories_2625729.id = a.category
LEFT JOIN jos_hpj_content_item_ad AS cff ON cff.id = a.ref_id AND a.content_type = 'com_hpj_content.ad'
LEFT JOIN jos_fields_values AS fields_values_min_maxyear ON fields_values_min_maxyear.item_id = a.ref_id AND fields_values_min_maxyear.field_id=8
LEFT JOIN jos_fields_values AS fields_values_min_max_2mileage ON fields_values_min_max_2mileage.item_id = a.ref_id AND fields_values_min_max_2mileage.field_id=10
LEFT JOIN jos_hpj_content_item_ad c ON c.`id` = a.`ref_id` AND a.`content_type`='com_hpj_content.ad'
WHERE a.state = 1 AND (`c`.title LIKE '%22%' OR c.`introtext` LIKE '%22%' OR a.synonym LIKE '%22%') AND a.content_type IN ('com_hpj_content.ad') AND a.ref_id IN (53,307,353,354,572,644,717,934,978,1056,1086,1128,1149,1199,1276,1294,1314,1324,1347,1351,1396,1411,1462,1470,1513,1537,1740,1741,1836,1861,1916,1988,1989,2005,2006,2124,2158,2266,2267,2268,2277,2511,2575,2577,2582,2585,2587,2654,2815,2894,2906,2975,3021,3179,3194,3219,3224,3239,0) AND a.state = 1
UNION (SELECT name FROM jos_users WHERE name LIKE '%22%')
```

I'm getting error

```
#1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns
```

If I remove UNION the sql query return result but if I keep UNION the error return
I'm trying to search the number in different tables in c.title or in name from jos_user and return the result

Comment: if you read the error message, what do you think it means? What do you expect the results to look like?

Comment: @danblack I don't know what that mean

Comment: guess. There are two SELECT statements. What columns do you think its talking about? If still stuck, answer the second question, and look back to what the [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) actually does.

Comment: @danblack sure it's talk about second select but I don't understand the error; I'm trying to find the 22 in c.title and also in user that has 22.

Answer (score 1):

As @danblack points out in comments, the error

```
#1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns
```

is saying that there's a different number of columns on the two `SELECT` statement. In

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT a.*,
                categories_2625729.title AS category_title,
                categories_2625729.id AS category,c.id as cid, 
                c.title, 
                '' as `introtext`, 
                'com_hpj_content.ad' as content_type, 
                '' as banner, 
                '' as `fulltext`, 
                '' as sheettext, 
                c.publish_up, 
                c.publish_down, 
                c.price, 
                c.advertiser_id, 
                c.seller_id, 
                c.sold, 
                c.soldupdated,0 AS is_favorite
  FROM ...
```

..you're select a lot more columns than in this

```sql
SELECT name
  FROM ...
```

The number of columns of those two `SQL` statements have to match in order for `UNION` to be able to add the results of the second query to the result of the first.

So this will work:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT c.title
  FROM ...
UNION
SELECT name
  FROM ...
```

because now both individual `SELECT` statements return just one column.

Comment: but I need to use a.* on my select

Comment: @pysql Obviously, that's not true.

Comment: @pysql That may be so. But you cannot use `UNION` the way you tried to. If you need an additional **column** in your result-set, then `UNION` is not the right way. If you need additional **rows** in your result-set, then you'll need to structure your second `SELECT` to match.

Comment: Is there any other way other than UNION to search in multiple tables ?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "search". I'm getting the impression that you're not the author of the first `SELECT` statement. And you're now trying to modify the query. You need to find out if you want extra rows **or** an extra column.

Comment: you can do multiple select statements. Then you don't need to read/understand/google this error, or solve the next problem of making a number of `user.name` rows look like `a.*,....`. Basic principle of SQL to be learnt here is that SQL returns ROWs, all of which have the same number of COLUMNS.

Comment: still didn't find a solution

Comment: @pysql Kindly read [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952). I think it will be better if you make an smaller example of your problem in a new Question.